# Receiving email on mailgun

Tags: email, smtp, mailgun, mx-record

I'm trying to use mailgun for it's SMTP service. The place I am trying to use it sends an email to the address entered as the "username":

postmaster@portal.example.com

[image]

I set up mailgun for receiving email within my DNS settings:

[image]

I've checked mailgun.org and made sure it sees the changes:

[image]

**I have no idea where to see these actual emails, I've checked around the mailgun dashboard but I'm not finding it, I've checked logs and saw that the message was "accepted" but no delivered log.**

I tried creating postmaster@portal.example.com on the host and then tried sending the validation code again but I didn't receive anything.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Mailgun to handle the incoming emails for you, you need to add Routes.

[Check the documentation on Routes](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html) to get started. It´s really quite straight forward.

Comment: Unfortunately we've run into a HUGE limitation in Mailgun's support for incoming emails.

Mailgun doesn't attempt to separate out the new reply from the email (strippedhtml field in posted routes) if there are more than 460 html tags in the email.

This is a huge undocumented limitation. (we found out from their support after reporting the bug)